# SQL Server query optimization for stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I need to improve the performance ofa stored procedure in SQL Server 2014.

Here is my procedure and I want optimise this procedure because this running to slowly.

Can anybody explain with some examples, which kind of query is better over what and in what situation?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Customer_SendMoney] 
    @CustomerId bigint,    
    @MobileNo nvarchar(15),    
    @Amount money,    
    @Comment nvarchar(250),    
    @PassPhrase nvarchar(50),
    @Type varchar(50) = null    
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnCode INT 
    DECLARE @RetVal BIGINT, @CustomerBalance MONEY,
            @CustomerMoneyRequestedId BIGINT, 
            @ToCustomerId BIGINT = 0,
            @TransactionId BIGINT, @CustomerAccount BIGINT,    
            @FromCustomerBalance MONEY = 0,
            @ToCustomerBalance MONEY = 0   

    IF EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Customer 
               WHERE Id = @CustomerId AND IsDeleted = 0 AND IsActive = 1)    
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            @CustomerBalance = Balance 
        FROM
            Customer 
        WHERE 
            Id = @CustomerId AND IsDeleted = 0 AND IsActive = 1 
       select @ToCustomerId = Id, @CustomerAccount = AccountNo,@ToCustomerBalance=Balance From Customer where convert(nvarchar,DecryptByPassPhrase(@PassPhrase, MobileNo)) = @MobileNo  and IsDeleted = 0 and IsActive = 1    
            if(@ToCustomerId > 0)
        begin
         if( lower(isnull(@Type,'regular')) <> 'suspention')
         begin
          set @ToCustomerBalance=@ToCustomerBalance+@Amount
         end
        END

        set @FromCustomerBalance=@CustomerBalance-@Amount
        if((@CustomerBalance > 0) and (@CustomerBalance >= @Amount) )    
        Begin     
           BEGIN TRAN TxnsenMoney
           BEGIN TRY 
            select @TransactionId = TransactionW2W+1 from MstGenerateTransactionID 
            where  [year]=datepart(yyyy,getdate()) and [month]=DATENAME(month,getdate())

            update MstGenerateTransactionID set TransactionW2W= @TransactionId 
            where  [year]=datepart(yyyy,getdate()) and [month]=DATENAME(month,getdate())
           --set @TransactionId = CONVERT(bigint,replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),111),'/','') + replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),114),':',''))       
        IF(@ToCustomerId > 0)    
        BEGIN
       --Update sender Customer
       update Customer set Balance = Balance - @Amount  where Id = @CustomerId    
       --Update receiver Customer
       if(lower(isnull(@Type,'regular')) <> 'suspention')
        begin
         update Customer set Balance = Balance + @Amount  where Id = @ToCustomerId   
        end  
       else
        begin
         update Customer set SuspentionAccount = isnull(SuspentionAccount,0) + @Amount  where Id = @ToCustomerId   
        end  

       INSERT INTO [TransactionW2W]    
        ([TransactionId]    
        ,[FromCustomerId]    
        ,[ToCustomerId]    
        ,[MobileNo]    
        ,[Amount]    
        ,[Comments]    
        ,[CreatedOn]
        ,[FromCustomerBalance]
        ,[ToCustomerBalance])    
        VALUES    
        (@TransactionId    
        ,@CustomerId    
        ,@ToCustomerId    
        ,@MobileNo    
        ,@Amount    
        ,@Comment    
        ,GETDATE()
        ,@FromCustomerBalance
        ,@ToCustomerBalance)                     

        End    --end IF @ToCustomerId > 0
        ELSE    
        BEGIN 
       --Update sender Customer              
       update Customer set Balance = Balance - @Amount where Id = @CustomerId    
       --print 'ELSE'
       INSERT INTO [TransactionW2W]    
       ([TransactionId]    
       ,[FromCustomerId]    
       ,[ToCustomerId]    
       ,[MobileNo]    
       ,[Amount]    
       ,[Comments]    
       ,[CreatedOn]
       ,[FromCustomerBalance])    
       VALUES    
       (@TransactionId    
       ,@CustomerId    
       ,@ToCustomerId    
       ,@MobileNo    
       ,@Amount    
       ,@Comment    
       ,GETDATE()
       ,@FromCustomerBalance)     

       INSERT INTO [NewCustomer]    
         ([FromCustomerId]    
         ,[MobileNo]    
         ,[Amount]    
         ,[CreatedOn]   
           )    
         VALUES    
         (@CustomerId    
         ,@MobileNo    
         ,@Amount    
         ,GETDATE()
          )    
        END --end ELSE @ToCustomerId > 0

     print @RetVal


      IF(@@TRANCOUNT >0 )    
         begin    
      set @RetVal = @TransactionId 
      print @RetVal      
         end    
         else    
         begin    
      RAISERROR('records not executed',16,1)    
         END
      COMMIT TRAN TxnsenMoney    
      END TRY  
      BEGIN CATCH 
      ROLLBACK TRAN TxnsenMoney
      set @RetVal = -1
      declare @error varchar(max)
      set @error= ERROR_MESSAGE()
     -- RAISERROR(@error,16,1) 
     print @error
      END CATCH     
    select @RetVal   
    End 
    END
    End
```

Comment: If this procedure works but just needs optimisation, then it would fit very well on our sister site [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: You need to look into both the query plan and statistics io output. You can also use performance metrics from plan cache. If you want someone to help, you also need to include your table & index structure. Without any details it's just guessing where the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Customer_SendMoney] 
    @CustomerId bigint,    
    @MobileNo nvarchar(15),    
    @Amount money,    
    @Comment nvarchar(250),    
    @PassPhrase nvarchar(50),
    @Type varchar(50) = null    
    AS    
    Begin    
       DECLARE @returnCode INT ,@RetVal bigint,@CustomerBalance money, @CustomerMoneyRequestedId bigint,@ToCustomerId bigint = 0,@TransactionId bigint,@CustomerAccount bigint,    
               @FromCustomerBalance money=0,@ToCustomerBalance money=0   

                IF EXISTS (select Id from Customer WITH(NOLOCK) where Id = @CustomerId and IsDeleted = 0 and IsActive = 1)  Begin    

                select @CustomerBalance = Balance from Customer WITH(NOLOCK) where Id = @CustomerId and IsDeleted = 0 and IsActive = 1 
                select @ToCustomerId = Id, @CustomerAccount = AccountNo,@ToCustomerBalance=Balance From Customer WITH(NOLOCK) 
                where convert(nvarchar,DecryptByPassPhrase(@PassPhrase, MobileNo)) = @MobileNo  and IsDeleted = 0 and IsActive = 1    
                    IF(@ToCustomerId > 0)
                        BEGIN
                        if( lower(isnull(@Type,'regular')) <> 'suspention')
                        BEGIN
                        SET @ToCustomerBalance=@ToCustomerBalance+@Amount
                    END
                END

        SET @FromCustomerBalance=@CustomerBalance-@Amount

       if((@CustomerBalance > 0) and (@CustomerBalance >= @Amount) )    
        Begin     
           BEGIN TRAN TxnsenMoney
                   BEGIN TRY 
                    SELECT  @TransactionId = TransactionW2W+1 
                    FROM    MstGenerateTransactionID  WITH(NOLOCK)
                    WHERE   [year]=datepart(yyyy,getdate()) and [month]=DATENAME(month,getdate())

                    update MstGenerateTransactionID set TransactionW2W= @TransactionId 
                    where  [year]=YEAR(GETDATE()) and [month]= MONTH(GETDATE())

               --set @TransactionId = CONVERT(bigint,replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),111),'/','') + replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),114),':',''))       
        IF(@ToCustomerId > 0)  BEGIN
       --Update sender Customer
             UPDATE Customer set Balance = Balance - @Amount  where Id = @CustomerId    
       --Update receiver Customer

        if(lower(isnull(@Type,'regular')) <> 'suspention') BEGIN 

             UPDATE Customer set Balance = Balance + @Amount  where Id = @ToCustomerId   

       END ELSE BEGIN 

           UPDATE Customer set SuspentionAccount = isnull(SuspentionAccount,0) + @Amount  where Id = @ToCustomerId   
       END  

       INSERT INTO [TransactionW2W]    
                  ([TransactionId] ,[FromCustomerId],[ToCustomerId] ,[MobileNo] ,[Amount],[Comments],[CreatedOn],[FromCustomerBalance],[ToCustomerBalance])    

       SELECT      @TransactionId ,@CustomerId ,@ToCustomerId ,@MobileNo ,@Amount ,@Comment,GETDATE(),@FromCustomerBalance ,@ToCustomerBalance                   

        END    --end IF @ToCustomerId > 0
        ELSE BEGIN 
           --Update sender Customer              
             UPDATE Customer set Balance = Balance - @Amount where Id = @CustomerId    
           --print 'ELSE'
             INSERT INTO [TransactionW2W]    
                       ([TransactionId] ,[FromCustomerId],[ToCustomerId] ,[MobileNo] ,[Amount] ,[Comments] ,[CreatedOn],[FromCustomerBalance])    

            SELECT @TransactionId ,@CustomerId  ,@ToCustomerId ,@MobileNo ,@Amount ,@Comment ,GETDATE() ,@FromCustomerBalance

            INSERT INTO [NewCustomer]    
                   ([FromCustomerId] ,[MobileNo] ,[Amount] ,[CreatedOn] )    

            SELECT @CustomerId,@MobileNo ,@Amount,GETDATE()

        END --end ELSE @ToCustomerId > 0

     print @RetVal


      IF(@@TRANCOUNT >0 )BEGIN
          set @RetVal = @TransactionId 
          print @RetVal      
     END ELSE BEGIN 
                  RAISERROR('records not executed',16,1)    
      END

      COMMIT TRAN TxnsenMoney    
      END TRY  

      BEGIN CATCH 

     ROLLBACK TRAN TxnsenMoney
      SET @RetVal = -1
      DECLARE @error varchar(max)
      SET @error= ERROR_MESSAGE()
     -- RAISERROR(@error,16,1) 
     print @error
      END CATCH     
    select @RetVal   
    End 
    END
    End
```

Comment: Hii Radha I Had made WITH(NOLOCK) Changes On Table.It will Allow you to Fetch The Fast If Any Locking Their On Table

Comment: Using NOLOCK is usually a bad idea. It can have different kind of unwanted sideaffects

Comment: YES James Z But Temporary I thought to give solution

Comment: That's really not something I would call a solution. It's an ugly hack that might improve performance, but could also cause serious problems now or later. Without knowing what the issue is, just randomly suggesting NOLOCK isn't the way to go.